# What is happening to my object when I split it into 4 to prepare it for 3d printing? If its the subdivision, I need it do what do I do?

Tags: modifiers

[image]

I'm designing an object to 3D print, and when i split it into 4, its not a perfect split. I dont know how to fix it, what do I do?

I split it by using planes, then rotated them along the x and y axis. then I use boolean twice to get a quarter of the object.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include how you split the model.